# Converse of Euler-Lucas Theorem?

Tags: number-theory

The Euler-Lucas Theorem states that every factor of $2^{2^n}+1$ ($n$th Fermat number) has the form $2^{n+2}k+1$.

Let $a$ be an integer. Is it true that, if every factor of $2^{2^n}a+1$ has the form $2^{n+2}k+1$, then $a=1$?

I found nothing on this online; please enlighten me if work has already been done on this.

Thanks,

Arkan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$n = 29014897 = 2^{2^2}*1813431 + 1$$

is a counterexample.

Its prime factors are

$$113=2^4*7+1$$
$$433=2^4*3^3+1$$
$$593=2^4*37+1$$

Comment: But I do not know counterexamples for n>2.

Answer (score 1):

A composite Fermat number F(n) will have a prime factor:

- f = $(6a-1)*2^{(n+2)}+1$ if n is odd,
- f = $(6b+1)*2^{(n+2)}+1$ if n is even.

  When a Fermat number has only two prime factors, the other prime factor is:
- f = $(6c+3)*2^{(n+2)}+1$.